# Modeling subdivision lines can be seen on my final modeling results even if object is flat shaded why?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

Every time I model and cut or subdivide a face even if it is a quad or tri the subdivision line shows the final result as you can see from the pics below even if the face is flat-shaded.  Why?  I would prefer if these do not show?  What am I doing wrong?  It happens on nearly all my models.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *Shade Flat* does what you think it does.

*Shade Flat* means, render each face with it's unique vertex normals. No averaging for any of them.

Like this:

[image]

See how this center vertex actually has 4 normals, attached to it? That's what you're seeing.

[image]

*Shade Smooth* means take vertices with multiple adjacent faces and "average" them out, turn them into one vertex normal.

Like so:

[image]

I think what you probably want is something like *Shade Smooth, Auto-Smooth* and a *Weighted Normal* Modifier.

[image]

[image]

Which looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank very much for the help.  Strangely though I removed the Auto Smooth and the model came out perfectly as I wanted.?

Comment: If you're using the weighted normal modifier without the autosmooth it does nothing. The difference between a mesh with decent topology and Shade smooth and Weighted Normals vs. just Shade Smooth is probably minimal. Autosmooth alone is usually for hard surface objects that you want to keep low poly but preserve somewhat decent shading.